# googleanalyticsR : How can I get page categories (content group) data?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to get data on page categories from Analytics, but it seems that this variable does not exist, as looked on https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/. 
If you do know how to get this data, the rest of the question does not apply.

If this indeed does not exists, those are the steps that I follow to get "grouped pages" data:

- In order to get page data, I use the `dim_filter` argument
- I define all the pages I need in `all.pages`
- The `function (x)` allows for the iteration over the different page names
- The actual iteration is done with the `map` function where I pass `all.pages` through the `function (x)`
- Then, I create a dataframe
- Because the actual name of the page used in the regex is not in the dataframe, I add them with the mutate function

```
all.pages <- c("page.name.1","page.name.2","page.name.3")

pages.ga <- function (x) { x.pages <- dim_filter(dimension="pagePath",operator="REGEXP",expressions=x)

x.filter <- filter_clause_ga4(list(x.pages))
x.results <<- google_analytics(ga_id,
                               date_range = c("2019-09-01","2019-11-30"),
                               metrics = c("bounceRate","pageviews","avgTimeOnPage"),
                               dim_filters = x.filter,
                               max = -1)

}

list.pages.results <- map(all.pages,pages.ga)
df.pages <- dplyr::bind_rows(list.pages.results)
df.pages <- df.pages %>% mutate(page.name = all.pages)
```

This works when there is no dimension but it is rather impossible to do with even a single dimension because the number of rows will not be the same as the length of `all.pages`.

Would anyone know how to overcome this ?

Thanks in advance to all of you !

Best, D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It exists under content group

```
ga:contentGroupXX
```

Where XX is an integer. To keep things a bit simpler, it would be easier if you go to [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) and type in content group under dimensions. The integers you have available will populate and you can explore which integer is the one you seek.

Comment: Dear Raymond, thank you so much for your rapid answer !!! That's perfect !!!

Comment: Happy to help!!